# Is it possible to add custom DNS entries to the Service Fabric DNS service

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

Service Fabric has its own built in [DNS service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice) that will automatically resolve service names to one of the IPs in the cluster running that service.  However, is it possible to add manual entries to this DNS server that do not map to a Service Fabric service?  For example, if I wanted `rediscache.cluster` to resolve to `10.0.100.4`, is that possible?

The alternative would be to make this a public DNS entry, however we'd rather hide our internal network addresses from the public.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add custom records to the DNS service.

As alternatives:

- you could consider to use a containerized [Redis](https://kb.objectrocket.com/redis/run-redis-with-docker-compose-1055) and deploy that in your cluster. This way it will be accessible through the DNS Service.

e.g. `sfctl compose create --deployment-name MyRedisApp --file-path docker-compose.yml`

- you can run a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) service that forwards traffic to the real Redis server in the network

e.g. `sfctl service create --app-id MyRedisProxyApp --name fabric:/MyRedisProxyApp/MyRedisProxy --service-type MyRedisProxyType --stateless --singleton-scheme --instance-count 1 --dns-name rediscache.cluster`

Comment: We're using Redis Enterprise which runs in its own private subnet and isn't containerized (nor do I think it can be).  The proxy solution doesn't really work, since Redis Enterprise uses DNS resolution for high availability.  We literally need to make a DNS zone that points to Redis nodes as name servers.  Plus, it still has the same problem; how does the proxy know which nodes are available.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed with Microsoft this is not possible.  Service Fabric DNS service is for resolution of SF services only.  There's no way to register services running external to it.

A possible alternative option is to use an [Azure Private DNS zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview) and connect it to the subnet the Service Fabric cluster is running in.